# Why isn't my router allowing my PAP2T to connect to my VoIP service?

Tags: router, firewall, voip, sip

My tech knowledge is middle-low: as you can see I'm not shy about getting into the interfaces for my router, but have no idea what the more complex settings mean.

I got a new wireless router (D-Link DIR-825), and have been trying to get our VoIP phone to run through it. It was working fine when I had the former router connected to my phone adapter (a Linksys PAP2T) and stopped working when the new DIR-825 was put into place.

I'm as far as having a dial tone, but can't call out (a long, long pause, followed by a fast busy signal), and calling in results in our phone ringing, but nothing but silence on pick-up and the phone that's calling in just hears our phone ringing forever.

Service with this company (Unlimitel, now owned by Primus) is frankly not great: my initial reply was "see our support page", and when I asked for more help than that, got an "open ticket" notification, this reply, and an immediate "closed ticket" notification:

> Hello,
>
> You'll need to adjust the firewall settings on your new router. Please
>   add our SIP server to your firewall's white list or allowed list.
>
> We use port UDP 5060 for SIP signaling. We use port UDP 10000-20000
>   for RTP voice packets.
>
> Our server's host name is sip02.unlimitel.ca and the IP address is
>   209.217.98.194.
>
> For further information on adjusting your routing please contact your
>   manufacturer.
>
> Thank you, [name] Primus Business HPBX and VOIP support 1-888-222-8577

I've tried forwarding the ports, as here:

[image: [forwarded ports]]

I can't find any way to add a SIP server to the firewall allowed/white list; here are the router options:

[image: firewall]

Here's what the PAP2T system looks like. I've blurred out my name and my phone number. When the phone is on-hook:

[image: PAP2T on hook]

While dialling (1-800-222-2222 is the number being dialled):

[image: PAP2T dialling]

While getting that busy signal:

[image: PAP2T busy]

I don't seem to have any specific information about connecting to the service in the current PAP2 configuration:

[image: PAP2T connections]

...but I haven't changed anything with the PAP2T adapter, only changed the main router, so I'm not sure if I *should* be touching any of the PAP2T settings.

I can also see that in my Line 1 settings on the PAP2T adapter, the URL and port match up with what the support ticket provided.

[image: PAP2T Line 1 settings]

As you can see, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do next.

I'm in an Ubuntu 12.04 environment, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if anyone out there is having VoIP problems with a DIR-825 out of the box, just remember to upgrade the firmware before trying to "fix" anything. It's a long and painful process, as the B1 firmware requires three separate firmware upgrades to get it up to recent, but the firmware resolved it in the end.